# How can I repair a joist with a large notch?

Tags: repair, wood, framing

We had to tear out some walls to properly vent the plumbing in the home we recently purchased and have discovered this on the joist above the staircase leading to the second floor. What repairs do I need to do, and would a sister suffice?

[image]

Comment: Or this? [What, if anything, do I do to repair notched floor joists?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/21534/35141)

Comment: Or this? [Repair or Replace Cut Floor Joist](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/105813/repair-or-replace-cut-floor-joist)

Comment: What's above the joist? What does it bear on? What's its span? Please revise your post to provide more information and context.

Comment: Strength axis police: The grain of the plywood is running parallel to this joist. You should post an image that includes more of the framing. Get the full length and a few feet running perpendicular to the notched joist. Are there nearby joists running parallel with this joist?